# Why is Keyboard.FocusedElement null when focus is inside WindowsFormsHost? It breaks WPF command routing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, xaml

I have a custom [RoutedUICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routeduicommand.aspx) `MyCommand` which gets executed via [ICommand.Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.execute.aspx). The top window has a binding to handle it:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="local:MainWindow.MyCommand" CanExecute="CanExecuteCommmand" Executed="CommandExecuted"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

This is the only handler for this command. I also have a [WindowsFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx) with WinForms' `TextBox` control inside (for the demo purpose). **When the focus is inside this `TextBox`, `MyCommand` doesn't reach the top window.** When the focus is inside a WPF's native `TextBox`, the command handler gets invoked as expected.

I've figured out **this is happening because [Keyboard.FocusedElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.focusedelement.aspx) is `null` when focus is inside `WindowsFormsHost`. Why is it `null` in this case, is it a WPF bug or design feature?** Am I missing something?

**I believe the command should be reaching the top window, regardless of where the focus is** (when it's the only handler in the visual tree and [FocusManager.IsFocusScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.isfocusscope.aspx) is set up correctly). I have a [related question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417648/inconsistency-in-wpf-command-routing-behavior-depending-on-the-ui-focus-state).

The project sources are available [here](http://goo.gl/kOecRM).

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfCommandTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCommandTest" 
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"  
        Title="MainWindow" Height="480" Width="640" Background="Gray">

    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="local:MainWindow.MyCommand" CanExecute="CanExecuteCommmand" Executed="CommandExecuted"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>

    <StackPanel Margin="20,20,20,20">
        <TextBox Name="textBoxOutput" Focusable="True" IsTabStop="True" Height="150" Text="WPF TextBox&#x0a;"/>
        <WindowsFormsHost Focusable="True" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True"  Height="150">
            <wf:TextBox x:Name="textBoxWf" Text="WinForms TextBox" />
        </WindowsFormsHost>
        <Button FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" Name="btnTest" Focusable="False" IsTabStop="False" Content="Test (ICommand.Execute)" Click="btnTest_Click" Width="200"/>
        <Button FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" Focusable="False" IsTabStop="False" Content="Test (Command property)" Command="local:MainWindow.MyCommand" Width="200"/>
        <Button FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" Name="btnClearFocus" Focusable="False" IsTabStop="False" Content="Clear Focus" Click="btnClearFocus_Click" Width="200"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

**C#:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfCommandTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static readonly RoutedUICommand MyCommand = new RoutedUICommand("MyCommand", "MyCommand", typeof(MainWindow));
        const string Null = "null";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += (s, e) => textBoxOutput.Focus(); // set focus on the TextBox
        }

        void CanExecuteCommmand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        void CommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var routedCommand = e.Command as RoutedCommand;
            var commandName = routedCommand != null ? routedCommand.Name : Null;
            Log("*** Executed: {0} ***, {1}", commandName, FormatFocus());
        }

        void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Log("btnTest_Click, {0}", FormatFocus());
            ICommand command = MyCommand;
            if (command.CanExecute(null))
                command.Execute(null);
        }

        void btnClearFocus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, this);
            Keyboard.ClearFocus();
            Log("btnClearFocus_Click, {0}", FormatFocus());
        }

        void Log(string format, params object[] args)
        {
            textBoxOutput.AppendText(String.Format(format, args) + Environment.NewLine);
            textBoxOutput.CaretIndex = textBoxOutput.Text.Length;
            textBoxOutput.ScrollToEnd();
        }

        string FormatType(object obj)
        {
            return obj != null ? obj.GetType().Name : Null;
        }

        string FormatFocus()
        {
            return String.Format("focus: {0}, keyboard focus: {1}",
                FormatType(FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this)),
                FormatType(Keyboard.FocusedElement));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's probably a imperfection. Please see this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scoberry/archive/2006/09/01/735844.aspx), section `Focus` - `Focus works differently for WPF and Windows Forms, and there were some rough edges around here that we were unable to fix`. And see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38507/Using-the-WPF-FocusScope) article, may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @AnatoliyNikolaev. I'm surprised they haven't fixed this since 2006, makes me think they may never will. This part is especially interesting: *If you have focus inside a WindowsFormsHost and either minimize/restore the form or show a modal dialog, the focus inside the WindowsFormsHost may be lost – the WindowsFormsHost still has focus, but the control inside it may not.* I don't care what element is focused inside `WindowsFormsHost`, but I'd expect `Keyboard.FocusedElement` to point to `WindowsFormsHost`. What do you think about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18417648/1768303)?

Answer (score 1):

To complete the interop Form-WPF you need to do this:

App.xaml.cs:

```
    public partial class App : Application
      {
      protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
        WindowsFormsHost.EnableWindowsFormsInterop();
        base.OnStartup(e);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Isn't it done automatically? Thanks anyway, I'll try this when I'm back from vacation.

Comment: I've added `WindowsFormsHost.EnableWindowsFormsInterop()` to the sample code in my question, and it didn't have any effect. The problem is still there: when the focus is inside WinForms' `TextBox`, `MyCommand` doesn't reach the top window.